# Vertically align text after div

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

I'm building an html bar graph using tables and nested divs and want to display the % as text immediately following the div bar.

I'm having a real problem centering this text vertically with the div - I've tried messing with vertical-align/line-height and various display options but to no avail. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I need a general solution - no absolute positioning.

The html:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Choice A
      <br>
      <div class="full">
        <div class="a"></div>
      </div>
      <span>50%</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The css:

```
td {
  text-align: left;
}
.full {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 250px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.a {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2n9aL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it different like

```
span {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xn6Eg/).

Or do

```
span {
    line-height: 25px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Xz7R/).

Comment: The first suggestion only appears centered because of my dimensions but the second solution works perfectly - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
vertical-align: top;
```

would be the css rule youd add there

Answer (score 0):

Above all answer are perfect, Also your HTML is ok just add

```
span {
        vertical-align: middle; /* As per your code */
        float:right;      /* This for span alignment */
        line-height:25px; /* This for center text */
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
vertical-align: text-top;
```